# how to install ffmpeg-static? m1/os x

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, apple-m1

I want to use library `eugeneware/ffmpeg-static` Link: [eugeneware/ffmpeg-static](https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static)

I'm using arch `'arm64'`
and os.platform() `'darwin'`

There is a binary in the document that corresponds to me, but it is not installed.

[image]

First time using the library and I have no knowledge of binaries. Can someone tell me how to install this library?

Comment: You need to manually build from GitHub or have to wait for version 4.4 https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static/issues/78

Comment: @Saugat thank, i wait 4.4...